# Changing a .bat to a .jar

Tags: batch-file, jar

Sorry if this is a very simple solution, but I have searched and couldn't find an answer, and have limited programming experience.  What I am trying to accomplish is making Minecraft download and run outside of `%appdata%` on windows. I would like it to download .minecraft to a separate folder and run from there. To accomplish this, I wrote a .bat file with this code:

```
set APPDATA=%CD%\data
bin\minecraft.exe
```

this worked PERFECTLY. The catch is, I have a friend's computer that I want to do the same on, which runs Ubuntu. Is there a way to write one .jar file that works exactly the same that would work for both `windows` and `linux?`  Thank you in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

No, just write

```
#!/bin/sh
APPDATA=somewhereorother/data bin/minecraft
```

chmod +x it, and use that for Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by chmod +x it?

Comment: [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) is a Linux command that changes file permissions or access. `+x` makes the file executable.